# Identifying a resistor array

Tags: identification, components

I have problems with identifying an component found when dissambling a hazard switch circuit from a old Mercedes Benz. It looks like a resistor array, but when meassuring the resistance between the pins it's not symetrical.

Can any of you identify this component?
It only has the numbers 337087 written on the back, and no amount of googling seems to find anything about it.

[image]

Comment: The pattern on the insulation suggests that what's underneath is not a regular pattern that would be used for an array of anything. If there were no other active components on the hazard switch then it's likely that there's a chip on board.

Comment: It looks like a custom component. Why it would be needed for a hazard light circuit is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

They had a bespoke resistor array (a kind of simple hybrid circuit) made that likely incorporated **all** the compatible resistors in the circuit, allowing them to reduce parts count and use a cheaper smaller PCB in the days before automatic assembly made such concepts moot (mounted cost of an SMT resistor is almost free these days).

Since MB put the flasher circuit into the switch assembly itself, space was also at a premium.

The array looks fine. If I was looking for a fault, and the relay coil/contacts were okay, I'd replace the electrolytic caps first, then any transistors.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed (most likely) a resistor array.

It's a type of precision array consisting of a resistive material patterned on a ceramic substrate, then laser-trimmed to the right resistances (or resistance ratios, if that matters more). They're commonly used in lab equipment like multimeters or oscilloscopes, and if you go looking for precision resistor arrays you'll likely find ones that look similar. [Caddock](http://www.caddock.com/Online_catalog/Mrktg_Lit/Type1776.pdf) makes them, for instance.

The blue protective coating isn't that common anymore, but you can find very similar-looking parts if you look for parts to repair old equipment, like [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Tektronix-307-0780-00-Precision-Resistor-Array-For-2215-Series-Oscilloscopes/233211716788) one I came across being sold on ebay (as a part for repairing a Tektronix 2215):

[image: A part that looks very similar to the one in the question, just a different size and a blurrier photo.]

Why one would be used in something as mundane as hazard blinkers in a car is beyond me. They're not cheap, and even if it's a luxury brand like Mercedes-Benz, I hardly think the hazard lights are where you'd put the extra expense.